# Vagrant: Sync centos folder to windows

Tags: windows, centos, synchronization, vagrant, virtual-machine

I am trying to sync folder from my vagrant virtual machine to Windows 7 machine.
I tried in the .vagrant file like this:

```
config.vm.synced_folder "/home/x/y/z/",  'C:/Users/me/Virtual Machines/nodejs'<br/>
```

And than I ran vagrant reload. I do not see the files of `/home/x/y/z/` in `C:/Users/me/Virtual Machines/nodejs` folder.

What is my mistakes here?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion it may be one reason :

1. You have wrong slash for path to guest(windows). In your case  **'C:\\Users\\me\\Virtual Machines\\nodejs'**